# Ruby: Only list items whose id's aren't contained in another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, matching

I have a Rails application in which users are matched based on their answers to questions.

When they answer a question their answer, along with the question id and some other information, is stored in a "user_answer" table. When the users load the list of questions, I want to only show the questions that they haven't already answered.

I've tried using scope through the model and a few tricks in the controller, but since I'm new to Ruby and Rails I'm having some trouble figuring it out.

Comment: Are you using rails 4.0?

Comment: We need a lot more information, like samples of your code. While you can try to explain it, seeing the code will tell us a lot more in a shorter period of time.

Answer (score 0):

Collections are sort of like arrays... you can do some simple math on them

```
@answered_questions = Question.joins(:user_answers).where(user_answers: {user_id: current_user.id})

@questions = Question.all - @answered_questions
```

`Question.all` would be however you're pulling up the questions, right?  But you should be able to subtract the @answered_questions from the whole that way.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! I wasn't aware you could do that. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing here but based on what you've said I'm imagining you have a users model a questions model and a user_answers model with the user_id, question_id and answer.

Based on those assumptions this may get you closer:

```
class User
  has_many answered_questions, :through => :user_answers, :source => :questions

  def unanswered_questions
    Question.all - answered_questions
  end

end
```

Note: there are more complicated ways to get this information that are more efficient but since you are just learning rails this might be better for now